# Android, load images from a specific folder into gallery view

Tags: android, image, view, gallery, sd-card

Hey guys how are you doing? i have setup a gallery view for my application and i would like to load images in this view from a specific image folder on my sdcard. Can someone please help me, as i searched alot and none of the provided solutions worked.

I have successfuly managed to load images from the RES/DRAWABLE folder into my gallery view, but never succeeded in my original plan.

This is the imageadapter class i use where i load the images from the RES/DRAWABLE folder

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter 
{

        public ImageAdapter(Context c) 
        {
            mContext = c;
        }

        public int getCount() 
        {
            return mThumbIds.length;
        }

        public Object getItem(int position) 
        {
            return position;
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) 
        {
            return position;
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
        {
            ImageView imageView;
            if (convertView == null)
            {
                imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
                imageView.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(100, 100));
                imageView.setAdjustViewBounds(false);
                imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
                imageView.setPadding(18, 18, 18, 18);
            } 
            else 
            {
                imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
            }

            imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);

            return imageView;
        }

        private Context mContext;

        private Integer[] mThumbIds = 
        {
               R.drawable.image_1,
               R.drawable.image_2,
               R.drawable.image_3,
               R.drawable.image_4
        };
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](http://www.brighthub.com/mobile/google-android/articles/64048.aspx) is a tutorial I used to do exactly what you want.  If it doesn't help I can post the code I used to grab pictures that are stored directly on the device (not the sd card).

Comment: heyy thanks, i just came here to say that i managed to solve it, looks like its almost the same way this guide discusses it... i used a fileinputstream and bufferedinputstream, i got the list of all files in the directory, read each into the fileinputstream and put that into the buffered, where then i created a bitmap and added it to an arraylist of bitmaps. thanks

Comment: ok now i have an new problem, i cannot load images more than 500kb, any solution to that? my application crashes

Comment: Most probable - you've got OutOfMemoryError. There is not so huge amount of memory given for application, and Bitmaps are not freed automatically - you should delete them manually with Bitmap.recycle(). You should add loading/unloading functionality for bitmaps depending on their visibility.

Comment: @aminet91 hi would you like to share the solution please?